# After searching for ListView items in Android, always open first item of ListView (Issue)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-search

When I opened the searched item, it is opening the first item of ListView not the searched one. Even if search and find the items successfuly.

Let me give examples:

- If I search for `Arrow`, I can get the `Arrow` but when clicked `Arrow` it is going to `Almost Human`, `Almost Human` is my first item of ListView
- If I search for `American` I'm getting `The Americans (first)` and `American Horror Story (second)` ( two results )
  search proccess is successful but if click `The Americans (second one)` it goes to second item of ListView.

What am I missing?

**My search code :**

```
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
}
```

**And here is the CustomListViewAdapter.java**

```
    public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
Context context;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);    

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    // holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(rowItem.getImageId());

    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ImageView gif = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    // UrlImageViewHelper.loadUrlDrawable(context, rowItem.getImageId());

    Ion.with(gif).load("http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android-icon/loading.gif");
    Drawable drawable=gif.getDrawable();
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(img, rowItem.getImageId(),drawable,
            600000);
    return convertView;
}
    }
```

**RowItem.java**

```
        public class RowItem<T> {
        private String imageId;
        private String title;
        private String desc;

        public RowItem(String imageId, String title, String desc) {
            this.imageId = imageId;
            this.title = title;
            this.desc = desc;
        }
        public String getImageId() {
            return imageId;
        }
        public void setImageId(String imageId) {
            this.imageId = imageId;
        }
        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title + "\n" + desc;
        }
    }
```

**MainActiviy.java**

```
            protected void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(onSaveInstanceState );
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // When clicked, Open the Next Screen
            Intent r = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KategoriActivity.class);
            r.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            r.putExtra("cat_img", asd[2][position]);
            r.putExtra("cat_id", asd[1][position]);
            r.putExtra("cat_id2", asd[1][position]);
            r.putExtra("cat_name",asd[0][position]);
            // r.putExtra("cat_img", bit[1][position]);
            startActivityForResult(r, position);


        }

    }); 


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {

            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result);
            asd = new String[3][jsonResponse.length()];
            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject js = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                asd[0][i] = js.getString("Category_Name");
                asd[2][i] = js.getString("Image");
                asd[1][i] = js.getString("Term_ID");

                RowItem item = new RowItem(asd[2][i], asd[0][i], "");
                rowItems.add(item);
            }

            adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope you can help me..

Comment: Has your ListView got a header? annoyingly the header is counted as the first item and can cause bugs like this

Comment: No I dont have header. thank you for your care.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308

Comment: is it possible to notifydatasetchanged after search or before selection of the search result in your code?

Comment: thank you francesco i will try.Even if the github example will work, still i am curious about my problm.
No I don't think so jimmy.

Comment: where is your code to handle the click of the list item?

Comment: I edited my question. still i couldn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally if you have an ArrayAdapter of of a custom type like `RowItem` it won't automatically handle filtering for you.  After all, how can it know which property of `RowItem` to filter?  You should override the `getFilter` method, and store the filtered list separately from the overall list in your adapter.  Something like this:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>
{
    private final ArrayList<RowItem>  mItems;
    private       ArrayList<RowItem>  mFilteredItems;
    private final Comparator<Object> mComparator;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<RowItem> items)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        mItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>(items);
        mFilteredItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>(items);
        mComparator = new Comparator<Object>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
            {
                String s1 = ((RowItem)o1).getTitle();
                String s2 = ((RowItem)o2).getTitle();
                return s1.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(mItems, mComparator);
        Collections.sort(mFilteredItems, mComparator);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFilteredItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RowItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFilteredItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(RowItem item)
    {
        return mFilteredItems.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return new Filter()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                mFilteredItems = (ArrayList<RowItem>)results.values;
                if (results.count > 0)
                {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            {
                List<RowItem> filteredResults = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
                for (RowItem item : mItems)
                {
                    if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())))
                    {
                        filteredResults.add(item);
                    }
                }

                Collections.sort(filteredResults, mComparator);
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;
                results.count = filteredResults.size();

                return results;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and in MainActivity:

```
        RowItem item = adapter.getItem(position)
        r.putExtra("cat_img", item.getImageId());
        r.putExtra("cat_id", item.getTermId());
        r.putExtra("cat_id2", item.getTermId());
        r.putExtra("cat_name", item.getTitle());
```

You Also have to add a termid field to RowItem, since it's in your JSON response...

Comment: I tried everything, but it is not working. I couldn't fix and find the alternative way of this error :
 `java.lang.ClassException: RowItem can not cast to java`

Comment: I'm confused. there is no method for `o1.gettitle()`.

Comment: You just need to cast it to RowItem...I edited the answer again.

Comment: It did not give any error but at the same time it did not effect anything.How is it possible? still the same position issue ? Where am i missing ? Hope you can help me..

Comment: You can't reference another array like this `asd[2][position]`... That makes the adapter useless.  I edited answer.  Make sure you add a termid to RowItem.

Comment: By the way , don't need to use any Filter code. My problem was all about the `setOnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 2):

### get the listView item id from the list you are passing in //your adapter class.

`here`for example if your adapter class is  ##

```
 class CustomAdapetr(Context context,ArrayList<RowItem>list_item){}
    //mainactivity
 myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       // HERE IS YOUR ITEM ID:):)
          int clickedItem=list_item.indexOf(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));

            }
        });
```

> cheers !!!! happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Inside ArrayAdapter are two lists: the original list with all the items, and the list of current items that the adapter will create views for. In the beginning, these two lists have the same items. When you filter on the adapter, the original list will continue to hold all the items, but the list being used for display will change because of the filter. When you remove the filter, the current list of items will change again to reflect the original list.

Suppose you have five items. After filtering, the list only shows the last item. The state of these lists then is

```
currentItems: { item5 }
originalItems: { item1 , item2 , item3 , item4 , item5 }
```

When you click this item, the ListView reports that position `0` is clicked. This is because the list being shown only has one item. If you then looked for the item at position 0 in the current list, you would get `item5`. But if you looked for the item at position 0 *of the original list*, you would get `item1`, which is *not* the data for the item that was clicked.

I suspect you have a reference to the original list and are using that to get the item data, even when the list is filtered. Instead use `adapter.getItem(position)`, it should give you the proper item.

Comment: thank you, how can i get the item without positon i don't know ? any idea ?

Comment: I suppose you could turn on stable ids

Comment: Can you give an example, I dont know how to use getItemId with my Adapter ?

Answer (score 1):

Im using something like this and its working fine for me. Im using string value in my list onsitemclick for search and display of desired activity

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


      String  itemValue    = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
      if (itemValue == "INDIA") {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, india.class);
          startActivity(intent);}
      else if (itemValue == "CHINA") {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, china.class);
          startActivity(intent);}

          else if (itemValue == "IRAQ") {
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, usa.class);
              startActivity(intent);
     }

    }
```