# Open selected item from filter results in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How i can open an item from filtered result list
In the listView, it is opening the first item of ListView not the searched one.
for example;  if the list view containing of :
item1
item2
item3
item4

if I make a search for item3 it will open item1   >> which is the first in listView

I tried to fixed based on this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566855/after-searching-for-listview-items-in-android-always-open-first-item-of-listvie)
I tried everything, but it is not working

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView m,m2;
ImageButton v1,v2,v3,v4;
private long backPressedTime = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    v2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    v3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    v4=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

    v1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Search.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
    v2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewAnd.class);
            startActivity(i2);

        }

    });
    v3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i3=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageTextListViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i3);

        }
    });
v4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i4=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sharus.class);
        startActivity(i4);
    }
});

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {        // to prevent irritating accidental logouts
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (t - backPressedTime > 2000) {    // 2 secs
        backPressedTime = t;
        Toast.makeText(this, " press to Exit ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {    // this guy is serious
        // clean up
        super.onBackPressed();       // bye
    }
  }
}
```

OfficesAdapter

```
public class OfficesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Office> implements Filterable{
private ArrayList<Office> items;
private ArrayList<Office> fitems;
LayoutInflater vi;
ArrayFilter mFilter = null;
public OfficesAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Office> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.fitems = items;
     vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {

        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.office, null);
    }
    Office o = fitems.get(position);
    if (o != null) {
            TextView num = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textNo);
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

            if (num != null) {
                num.setText(o.getOfficeNo());}
            if (tt != null) {
                  tt.setText(o.getNameAr());}                            
            if(bt != null){                 
                bt.setText(o.getNameEn() );}

    }
    return v;

}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null)
        mFilter = new ArrayFilter();

    return mFilter;
}
@Override
public Office getItem(int position) {    
    return  fitems!=null ? fitems.get(position) : null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {    
    return fitems!=null ? fitems.size() : 0;  
}
private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // We implement here the filter logic
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            results.values = items;
            results.count = items.size();
        }
        else {
            // We perform filtering operation
            ArrayList<Office> nList = new ArrayList<Office>();

            for (Office o : items) {
                if (o.getNameEn().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) || o.getNameAr().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    nList.add(o);
            }

            results.values = nList;
            results.count = nList.size();

        }
        return results;


    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
        // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
        if (results.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else {
            fitems =  (ArrayList<Office>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }}}
```

Search

```
public class Search extends Activity {
private OfficesDataSource datasource;
Context context;
Activity activity;
ListView lview = null;
EditText filterText = null;
OfficesAdapter adapter=null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    context = this;
    activity = this;

    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOffices);
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    datasource = new OfficesDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    ArrayList<Office> values = datasource.getAllOffices("");
    adapter = new OfficesAdapter(lview.getContext(), R.layout.office, values);
    //send adapter to list view lvItems to view the items 
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);



    lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch( arg2 )
            {
               case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(Search.this, S00.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity);
                break;   
              case 1:  Intent i1 = new Intent(Search.this, S01.class);     
                startActivity(i1);
                break;
              //.... etc....


        }   
     } 


});
}


private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);


    }

 };   

}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that opens a file.

Comment: sorry I mean open selected item.  I've edited my quistion

Comment: There is nothing in your code that 'opens a selected item'. What would that be by the way?

Comment: I added the code, hope u can help me and sorry for miss understanding. my code opening the first item of ListView not the searched one.